# How can ant check if drive D exists

Tags: ant

I want to copy some files to D drive, but in the test environment there is only C drive, so I want to add condition to check if there is D drive first, else copy the file to C.

```
<if>
                <available file="D:\" />
                <then>
                    <copy todir="D:shared/CountrySettings" overwrite="true">
                        <fileset dir="${dist.CountrySettings.dir}/cfg" />
                    </copy>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <copy todir="C:shared/CountrySettings" overwrite="true">
                        <fileset dir="${dist.CountrySettings.dir}/cfg" />
                    </copy>
                </else>
            </if>
```

seems not correct, How can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the main problem is that you're missing the first slash in your destination directories. `D:shared/CountrySettings` should be `D:/shared/CountrySettings` (or D:\shared\CountrySettings since you're on Windows).

I would also highly recommend using native Ant's `condition` task whenever possible instead of ant-contrib's if/else functionality.

```
    <condition property="dest.dir" value="D:\shared\CountrySettings" else="C:\shared\CountrySettings">
        <available file="D:\" />
    </condition>

    <copy todir="${dest.dir}" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="${dist.CountrySettings.dir}/cfg" />
    </copy>
```